# How to create a matrix with a normal distribution in it in r?

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, normal-distribution

I want to have a pixel grid filled with the values of a normal distribution in it like in the picture below

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Comment: How should be the logic to calculate the values? What did you tried to produce your result? The graphic type is a ***heatmap***.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what you want to do. Are you asking how to sample from a bivariate normal distribution? Or how to create a heatmap? Or how to overlay text onto a heatmap? But ok, I'll bite...

Here is an example from scratch how to generate data and produce a heatmap with numbers indicating counts per bin box.

```
# Create sample data
require(MASS);
set.seed(2017);
mu <- c(5, 5);
sigma <- diag(c(2, 2));
df <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(10000, mu = mu, Sigma = sigma));
colnames(df) <- c("x1", "x2");

# Bin breaks
nbins <- 20;
breaks_x <- seq(floor(min(df$x1)), ceiling(max(df$x1)), length.out = nbins);
breaks_y <- seq(floor(min(df$x2)), ceiling(max(df$x2)), length.out = nbins);

# Frequency table
freq <-  as.data.frame(table(
    as.numeric(cut(df$x1, breaks = breaks_x)),
    as.numeric(cut(df$x2, breaks = breaks_y))));

# Plot matrix
mat <- diag(nbins) * 0;
mat[cbind(freq[, 1], freq[, 2])] <- freq[, 3];
image(breaks_x, breaks_y, mat, col= rainbow(10));
text(breaks_x[freq$Var1], breaks_y[freq$Var2], freq$Freq, cex = 0.8);
```

[image]

Or if you're only interested in a heatmap, you can use `ggplot2` with `stat_bin2d`.

```
require(ggplot2);
ggplot(data.frame(df), aes(x1, x2)) + stat_bin2d(bins = 20) + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(32));
```

[image]

Or `gplots::hist2d`.

See [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/5-ways-to-do-2d-histograms-in-r/) for more options...

Comment: Thank you very much!
It could be a bit easier since I dont understand every line of your code...:-)

Comment: @Robert You're welcome. As you've noticed, your question has attracted quite a bit of negative rating. That's because SO is not a forum for you to ask others to write the code for you; nor is this a forum to teach you R. Questions such as yours are usually frowned upon. Instead, SO members are more than happy to help debug/improve code, **after you've spent a considerable and visible amount of research yourself**. So as a piece of advice for the future, you should [take the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: Got it. But since I dont understand the code I want to try it by myself.